# How do I read input as a string and store each word (a word is anything separated by a space) to a 2d array using malloc, strtok_r?

Tags: c, malloc

I m new to C, I know certain functions that help for this but I m having a tough time piecing things together.

process I used so far: Used readline to get input, counted the number of words using strtok_r, malloced space for the words, counter characters in each word and malloced space for that, and then printed the array.

However when running this, I get a seg fault.

```
while(inStr = readline("# "))
 {
  
   int totalWords = totalWordsInInput(inStr);
   //malloc the rows (array of pointer-total number of words)
   char** theBigArray = (char**) malloc((totalWords+1)*(sizeof(char*)));           //+1 so we can save a null
   for(int i = 0; i <= totalWords; i++)
   {
       theBigArray[i] = NULL;
   }
   //malloc for each word
   char* ptr = inStr;
   char* saveptr;
   for(int i = 0; i < totalWords; i++, ptr = NULL)     //for every word
   {
       int totalChar = strlen((strtok_r(ptr, " ", &saveptr)));
       theBigArray[i] = (char*) malloc((totalChar+1)*(sizeof(char)));
       for(int j = 0; j <= totalChar; j++)
       {
           theBigArray[i][j] = '\0';
       }
   }

   //populate the malloced array
   char* ptr1 = inStr;
   char* buffer1;
   int k = 0;
   for(int i = 0; (i < totalWords) && (buffer1 = strtok_r(ptr1, " ", &ptr1)); i++)
   {
       theBigArray[i] = buffer1;
   }


   //printing the malloced array
   for(int i = 0; i < totalWords; i++)
   {
       printf("%s", theBigArray[i]);
   }
 }
  
 


  int totalWordsInInput(char* inputString)
  {
   int counterWords = 0;
   char* buffer;
   char* ptr = inputString;

   while(buffer = strtok_r(ptr, " ", &ptr))
   {
       counterWords++;
   }

   return counterWords;
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: Additionally, in C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). `sizeof(char)` is defined as `1` and can be omitted from calculations. Recommended to use the derefernced pointer for type-size, e.g. `char **theBigArray = malloc ( (toalWords+1) * sizeof *theBigArray );`. You only need `+1` on the pointers if you are providing a *sentinel `NULL`* as the last pointer. If you are reading words `char buf[256]; while (fscanf (fptr, "%255s", buf) == 1) { /* alloc/add word */ }`

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code:

- Assigning NULL to bigArray[i]
- Too many loops, since it's possible to join the "instructions" that you are doing in different loops
- Incomplete Code
- There are no warnings, details, and errors provided to help everyone to answer you
- Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' when get the strlen(...): you should cast it at least (int).
- Unused variable 'k'
- You should first allocate memory for inStr and after take the user input. And furthermore, after that you allocate memory for an array or anything else, you should check that it was allocated fine.

Here you are the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LEN 100

int totalWordsInInput(char *);
void getError(char *);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char *text = (char *) malloc(MAX_LEN);
    if (!text) getError("Input text");
    
    printf("\nInsert some words: ");
    fgets(text, MAX_LEN - 1, stdin);
    text[strcspn(text, "\n")] = '\0';
    text = (char *) realloc(text, strlen(text) + 1);
    if (!text) getError("Input text");
    
    int totalWords = totalWordsInInput(text);
    char **bigArray = (char **) malloc(totalWords * sizeof(char *));
    if (!bigArray) getError("big Array");
    
    char *currentWord, *savePtr = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    for (currentWord = strtok_r(text, " ", &savePtr); currentWord != NULL; currentWord = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &savePtr)) {
        int totalChar = (int) strlen(currentWord);
        bigArray[i] = (char *) malloc(totalChar + 1);
        
        if (!bigArray[i]) getError("bigArray[i]");
        strcpy(bigArray[i], currentWord);
        bigArray[i][totalChar + 1] = '\0';
        i++;
    }
    
    printf("\nSingle words:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < totalWords; i++) printf("%s\n", bigArray[i]);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    return 0;
}

int totalWordsInInput(char *inputString) {
    int counterWords = 0;
    char *text = (char *) malloc(strlen(inputString) + 1);
    if (!text) getError("total Words In Inpu Text");
    strcpy(text, inputString);
    
    char *word, *savePtr = NULL;
    for (word = strtok_r(text, " ", &savePtr); word != NULL; word = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &savePtr)) {
        counterWords++;
    }
    return counterWords;
}

void getError(char *errorMessage) {
    printf("\nError allocating memory for %s...", errorMessage);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Personal tip:

- I prefer to use fgets(...) instead of readline(...)
- I used a getError(char *) procedure in order to print error when memory wasn't allocated successfully

I hope that it helps you at least just a bit.

Best regards,
Denny